# How to create a table, move the file and rename the file at the same time in SSIS

Tags: for-loop, ssis

Need help with SSIS

create a table and save the result as a file-> make 5 copies of this file into one folder and rename each file as 1,2,3,4,5

Anyone can give some hints about this question?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps.

1. Create table in DB.
2. Load the data into table.
3. Run DB unload to file in sub component.
4. Keep the above sub component in Foreach loop and parametrise the file name on each loop execution.

Comment: can you please be specific? like how to make 5 copies in the same folder with the name 1,2,3,4,5? Thanks.

Comment: I thought it should use the for loop container? Do you know why cannot use the for loop? Thansk.